# Errors when running Rails application in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I'm new to configuring Rails applications in production mode. My Rails application is working correctly, but when I try to run it in production mode it crashes at startup:

```
 rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

here everything is fine, and:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
/Users/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rails-4.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': /Users/dawid/workspace/demioorg/Dineria/backend/app/controllers/users/users_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
      render_status: 200,
```

I'm just wondering why it works in development mode and not in production mode? What can cause that error?

**EDIT:**

```
class Users::UsersController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json

  def is_user
    if current_user.present?
      render_status: 200,
        json: {
          success: !User.find_by_name(params[:name]).blank?
        }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: can you show your users_controller?

Comment: I edited my question with users_controller. But I don't know why it works correctly only in development mode

Comment: Does it work if you try:

render :json => {success: ...}, :status => 200

?

Comment: change `render_status: 200` >> `render status: 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this format instead:

```
render :status => 200, 
       :json   => {success: User.exists?(:name => params[:name])}
```

I think it looks prettier, and is more logical.

Also `.exists?` looks a little better than your code.

Comment: Also .exists? looks much better

Answer (score 1):

The [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) shows how to use the `:status` option for `render`:

2.2.11.4 The :status Option

Rails will automatically generate a response with the correct HTTP status code (in most cases, this is 200 OK). You can use the :status option to change this:

```
render status: 500 
render status: :forbidden
```